# How can I make Geany use the Microsoft Windows Terminal?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, geany, windows-terminal

### The Goal

I would like to configure Geany so that it launches my programs in [Microsoft Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows).

### What I know

I know that the terminal emulator can be selected under *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Tools* → *Terminal*, where you can input an arbitrary shell command for Geany to execute. Before executing the command, Geany looks for a `%c` placeholder and replaces it with the path to a bat file and a few arguments.

For example, Geany's default terminal command on Windows is:

```
cmd /q /c %c
```

And the command Geany executes is therefore something like

```
cmd /q /c "C:\Program Files\Geany\geany-run-helper" "C:\path\to\working\dir" 0 python file_name.py
```

### The Problem

The problem is that once the Windows Terminal (executable [`wt`](https://ss64.com/nt/wt.html)) is added to this command, something goes wrong with unescaping. Here are some commands I've tried:

- `wt %c` results in

  > [error 0x80070002 when launching `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\libexec\geany\geany-run-helper" "D:\Users\Aran-Fey\Desktop\temp {e}" 0 python -i untitled.py']
- `wt "%c"` results in

  > [error 0x80070002 when launching `C:\Program Files "(x86)\Geany\libexec\geany\geany-run-helper D:\Users\Aran-Fey\Desktop\temp" "{e} 0 python -i untitled.py"']
- `wt cmd /q /c %c` and `wt cmd /q /c "%c"` result in

  > 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  > operable program or batch file.
  >
  > [process exited with code 1]

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `wt cmd /q /c %c` will work, or at least, it works on my system.  Only `wt cmd /q /c "%c"` fails with the error you saw

Comment: @AnonCoward That's interesting, it works if there's no space in the path to the file. I guess Geany doesn't escape the path if it's not necessary, which then somehow makes `wt` or `cmd` unescape the remaining arguments correctly. Crazy. Windows is such a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on the same issue with `wt cmd /q /c %c` not working.

The following works for me: `wt cmd /q /c call %c`

**Edit:**

For a reason I don't know, `wt cmd` does not handle properly spaces in arguments.

Try this:

Create **test.bat**:

```
echo %1
```

### Case 1

**test.bat** in *C:/test.bat*

1. Run `wt cmd /k "C:/test.bat" "no_space_here"` -> works
2. Run `wt cmd /k "C:/test.bat" "space here"` -> works

### Case 2

**test.bat** in *C:/My Folder/test.bat* (note that path has a space)

1. Run `wt cmd /k "C:/My Folder/test.bat" "no_space_here"` -> works
2. Run `wt cmd /k "C:/My Folder/test.bat" "space here"` -> does NOT works
3. Run `wt cmd /k "C:/My^ Folder/test.bat" "space here"` -> works
4. Run `wt cmd /k "C:/My Folder/test.bat" "space^ here"` -> does NOT works

Geany default installation folder is under *C:\Program Files\Geany*, which contains a space, and the `%c` placeholder is replaced by:

`"C:\Program Files\Geany\libexec\geany\geany-run-helper" "Current\working\directory" some_args`

If your CWD has a space in its path you'll fall into **Case 2.2** and have an error.

**NB:** wrapping everything with double quotes does not work.

Using `CALL` runs the script `geany-run-helper.bat` and passes arguments without parsing error (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/23514286) for detailed behavior).

Comment: [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html): *"Call one batch program from another, or call a subroutine."*

Comment: Why does CALL make a difference?